# How to unlock the phone on incoming call?

Tags: android

I am making a project in which i am using a transparent screen with a button on incoming call screen. It is working fine if the phone is unlock but if the phone is in lock condition and the call arrive on phone than firstly i have to unlock the phone

The code that i used is...

```
public class Recevo extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Intent i= new Intent(context,Servo.class);
        int state = tm.getCallState();

      if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){

            String number=intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");
            Log.i("State", "Call is Ringing");



            context.startService(i);

        }else if (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

            Log.i("State", "Idle State");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call is Idle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            context.stopService(i);

        } else if (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {


            //Log.i("State", "Call is Ringing");
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Phone is Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

}


public class Servo extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in servo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Thread t=new Thread(new Times());
        t.start();
    }

    public class Times extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                Intent i = new Intent(Servo.this,Blank.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Blank extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blank);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AudioManager audio1 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        //audio1.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audio1.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        finish();
    }
```

---

Update 1

```
public class CallerService extends Service implements
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

String number;

boolean a;
private TextToSpeech tts;
int callState;
TelephonyManager mgr;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate();

tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
AudioManager audio1 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

int maxVolume = audio1.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float percent = 2.0f;
int seventyVolume = (int) (maxVolume*percent);
audio1.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, seventyVolume, 0);

Thread t=new Thread(new Times());
t.start();

}

public class Times extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Intent i = new Intent(CallerService.this,Blank.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStart(intent, startId);

number = intent.getStringExtra("phnumber");


//fetchContacts();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) 
 {
         tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
         fetchContacts();
 } 
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if (tts != null) {
    tts.stop();
    tts.shutdown();
}
super.onDestroy();

}



public void fetchContacts() {

/*  tts.speak("Hello everyone", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
        null);*/

String phoneNumber = null;

Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;

String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;

String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
        null);

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String contact_id = cursor
                .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));

        int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

        if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

            Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                    PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { contact_id }, null);

            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {

                phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));

                a = PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number,
                        phoneNumber);
                callState= mgr.getCallState();

              /*if(!a){             

                    if(callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

                        callState = mgr.getCallState();

                        if (callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                            tts.stop();
                            tts.shutdown();
                            break;                  

                            }else if (callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                                tts.stop();
                                tts.shutdown(); 
                            break;  
                            }               

                        tts.speak("Unknown Calling", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                                null);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
                }                   

                else */if (a) {

                    String contname = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (!contname.equals(null)) {


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                contname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        if(callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

                            callState = mgr.getCallState();


                            if (callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                                tts.stop();
                                tts.shutdown();
                                break;                  

                                }else if (callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                                    tts.stop();
                                    tts.shutdown(); 
                                break;  
                                }               

                            tts.speak(contname + " Calling", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                                    null);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    }
                }

            }

            phoneCursor.close();

        }


    }

}
if(!a){             

    if(callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

        callState = mgr.getCallState();

        if (callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
            break;                  

            }else if (callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                tts.stop();
                tts.shutdown(); 
            break;  
            }               

        tts.speak("Unknown Calling", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                null);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}       
}

}
```

in the Blank class

```
public class Blank extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button b;
    Window window;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blank);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        window = this.getWindow();

        // use Window.addFlags() to add the flags in WindowManager.LayoutParams
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AudioManager audio1 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        //audio1.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audio1.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        finish();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
private Window window;

@Override
protected void onResume() {    
   super.onResume();

   // get the window of your activity
   window = this.getWindow();

   // use Window.addFlags() to add the flags in WindowManager.LayoutParams
   window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
   window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
   window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

}
```

**Note:** You can put this code in `onCreate()` as well, but I would suggest to put it in `onResume().`

`FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` - when set the window will cause the keyguard to be dismissed, only if it is not a secure lock keyguard.

`FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` - special flag to let windows be shown when the screen is locked

`FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`  - when set as a window is being added or made visible, once the window has been shown then the system will poke the power manager's user activity (as if the user had woken up the device) to turn the screen on.

Comment: if i add any code with this it shows the transparent screen on back of incomingcall screen or when i cut the incoming call

Comment: i have updated code and using this code my app is able to speak the caller name and i added a button on transparent screen i.e if the user is clicking on that button it must get silent

Comment: it is working good if i am doing this work in two different projects but when i am doing this in single project it running the transparent screen when the call is cut